# R: Add relative axes to on the right and top of the plot

Tags: r, plot, axes, multiple-axes

I would like to make a simple plot look a little bit better. To do so would like to add relative axes in addition to the absolute values. I think I can use axis(3,...) to do this but I haven't figured out how.

Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you

try something like

```
  x=1:10
    y=x^2

    plot(y~x)
    axis(3, at=x,labels =mean(x)-x)
```